# SSIS Kingswaysoft error for JSON source

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

I am using JSON Source component in a package, it is working fine on my local machine but when I deploy in server am receiving the following error.

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSBufferManager100.FindColumnByLineageID(Int32 hBufferType, Int32 nLineageID)
>      at KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.ProductivityPack.JsonSourceComponent.yhs.cgd(IDTSOutputColumn100 kbk, IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 kbl)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__61`4.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.ProductivityPack.JsonSourceComponent.bdc()
>      at KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.ProductivityPack.JsonSourceComponent.PreExecute()
>      at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)

Comment: Are you using identical data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error “Value does not fall within the expected range”, it seems to be an issue caused by the SSIS optimization design, it happens when you don’t have all the output attached to a destination component.

In this case, either of the following two options can solve the issue properly:

- Set the RunInOptimizedMode property to False in the Properties window
  at Data Flow Level (see figure 1). This setting can be found after
  you click the blank area on your data flow designer.
- Alternatively, you can try to direct other outputs of the JSON Source component to an SSIS Destination component which can take care of this situation as well.

Can you please give it a try and see if it helps?

[Figure 1]

[image]